# My build on `master` branch runs twice with semantic-release

Tags: semantic-release

I have a working demo where I have 2 builds running every-time i merge to master. i.e, one is by my user & the other is by semantic-release-bot which is always [skip-ci]

https://github.com/adeelibr/learn-semantic-release/commits/master (like the image below)

[image]

I am using TravisCI for this, can anyone kindly tell what is it that I am doing wrong here?

Also after every release my package-lock.json file updates..

Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's exactly the problem you have here?
Everything seems to work as intended. On a release semantic-release push a commit with the updated package.json and the commit is skipped by the CI as intended.

Comment: package.json is never updated, because it is semantically released. The changelog, github release, and publish to npm is done when my pr is merged on master.

But a useless semantic-bot-release is issued which at the end does nothing

Comment: `package.json` is not updated because you don't use a plugin that update it such as `@semantic-release/npm`.
I don't know what you mean by "a useless semantic-bot-release is issued"...maybe you refer to the commit that is done on the release to push the changelog (and the `package.json` if you were updating it). If you don't want that commit then don't use the `@semantic-release/git` which only purpose is to make that commit.

Comment: I have updated the issue & added an image, hopefully that'll describe what I mean with a useless release commit.

Comment: Oh never mind I figured out.

Comment: A silly understanding at my end. The first commit highlighted at my end is that of my changes & the one in red is that where semantic-release-bot adds a changelog, releaselog,  publishes to npm etc.